# Two Input Buttons on same line

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get two buttons to be on the same line.

Any suggestion?

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h3 class="panel-title">Please login your account...</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">

                    <form action="" method="post" role="form" class="form-horizontal">

                    <input class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-top:.75em;width: 100%; height: 32px; font-size: 13px;" type="submit" name="commit" value="Sign In"><input class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-top:.75em;width: 100%; height: 32px; font-size: 13px;" type="submit" name="commit" value="Sign In">
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/a65oc6f3/

Comment: Since you're already using "btn-primary" as the class, just bind some CSS to it e.g. display:inline-block; width:30px;

Comment: Then don't give them both `width:100%`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/a65oc6f3/5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want both buttons to have a 100% width, try this:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h3 class="panel-title">Please login your account...</h3>

            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <form action="" method="post" role="form" class="form-horizontal">
                    <input class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-top:.75em;width: 50%; height: 32px; font-size: 13px; float:left" type="submit" name="commit" value="Sign In">
                    <input class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-top:.75em;width: 50%; height: 32px; font-size: 13px" type="submit" name="commit" value="Sign In">
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Fiddle: [here](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddlerJeff/a65oc6f3/8/)

Answer (score 1):

set the Width to 50% on both buttons or put them in a 1X2 table and set the width of the table to 100%

Answer (score 1):

just updated your fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/a65oc6f3/9/

First method:

pls add width:45%; to both buttons not 100% and

1. margin-left:5%; to your right button
   or
2. float:right  to your right button

second method:

you can add row and two cols

and if you want to make these buttons in one line on mobile also than add col-xs-5 to both cols
for example

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-5 col-xs-5">
       <input class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-top:.75em;width: 100%; height: 32px; font-size: 13px;" type="submit" name="commit" value="Sign In">
    </div> <!-- col-6 closed -->

    <div class="col-md-5 col-xs-5 pull-right">
       <input class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-top:.75em;width: 100%; height: 32px; font-size: 13px;" type="submit" name="commit" value="Sign In">
    </div> <!-- col-6 closed -->
</div> <!-- row ends -->
```

for more well documentation visit bootstrap forms and buttons documentation.
http://getbootstrap.com/css/#buttons

Answer (score 0):

Wrap you input boxes with div's that have class of col-md-6 and set the input's width to 100%, like shown below:

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title">Please login your account...</h3>

    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <form action="" method="post" role="form" class="form-horizontal">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6">
                <input class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-top:.75em;width: 100%; height: 32px; font-size: 13px; float:left" type="submit" name="commit" value="Sign In">
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
                    <input class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-top:.75em;width: 100%; height: 32px; font-size: 13px" type="submit" name="commit" value="Sign In">
</div>
</div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```